# yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z date format in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time, date-formatting

I am consuming an API which returns a date like this `2016-05-05T20:59:31.000Z`. This format is new for me, so, What is the name of this date format? and, how can I treat it in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date and [`Time.parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-parse) has no trouble parsing it:

```
require "time"

str = "2016-05-05T20:59:31.000Z"
p Time.parse(str)
# => 2016-05-05 20:59:31 UTC
```

Comment: From the linked page: "If the time is in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC), add a Z directly after the time without a space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset."

Comment: Sorry, I delete my first comment by mistake. I asked if `Z` means UTC zone time. That´s it! works very fine. Because I am in Bogotá, Colombia, I've added it `in_time_zone('Bogota')` in order to show the date in my time zone. Thank you!

Comment: `DateTime` is meant for historical dates, you should use `Time` instead. And there's also a dedicated class method `iso8601`.

Comment: @Stefan what does 'historical dates' mean?

Comment: @IvánCortésRomero see [When should you use DateTime and when should you use Time?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F)